# "Proibido fumar e fuguear" ou "Proibido fumar e foguear" ?Vi escrito da primeira forma

Tags: significado, ortografia, verbos, acordo-ortográfico

"Proibido fumar e fuguear" ou "Proibido fumar e foguear" ?Vi escrito da primeira forma. ou as duas estao corretas

Comment: Já procurou nos dicionários?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A grafia correta da palavra é "foguear", e não "fuguear".

Portanto, a frase correta é: **"Proibido fumar e foguear"**.

1 Pôr fogo a, queimar: Afogueou os papéis velhos.

Tem o mesmo significado de "afoguear".

https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/foguear/

Comment: Bem vindo ao site. Normalmente pedimos ao contribuidores que enriqueçam as respostas com referênicas à gramática, dicionários ou outras obras de linguística para dar algum suporte teórico à resposta.

Comment: Adicionei as referências teóricas. Obrigado.